# How to read digits from file to matrix, no delimeter

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a data stored in below format, no delimeter and digit domain is {0,1}. With using octave, taking the digits and storing them in martix is reaised a problem for me. I have not managed below scnerio. So, How can I take those digits and store them on matrix as told at below?

```
Data in File, 32 x 32 digits

00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000001111110000000000000000
        ...
00000010000000100001000000000000


how to store data
matrix[1, 1:32] = 00000000000000000000000000000000
matrix[2, 1:32] = 00000000001111110000000000000000

            . . .
matrix[32, 1:32] = 00000010000000100001000000000000

OR

matrix[1, 1:32] = 00000000000000000000000000000000
matrix[1, 33:64] = 00000000001111110000000000000000

    . .  .
matrix[1, 993:1024] = 00000010000000100001000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to read the data as a string first:

```
octave> textread('foo.dat', '%s', 'headerlines', 2)
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = 00000000000000000000000000000000
  [2,1] = 00000000001111110000000000000000
  ...
}
```

If these are binary representations of decimals, you may find `bin2dec()` useful.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick (though I don't know how well that third input to `fread` and `arrayfun` work with Octave, tested this on Matlab):

```
fid         = fopen('a.txt','rt');
str         = fread(fid,inf,'char=>char');
st          = fclose(fid);
qrn         = str==10|str==13;
str(qrn)    = [];
yourMat     = reshape(arrayfun(@str2num,str),find(qrn,1)-1,[]).'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have header lines, you can read the text in as a cell arrray of strings like so:

```
C = textread('names.txt', '%s');
```

Then, in general for all numbers from 0 to 9, you can transform this into a matrix like so:

```
M = vertcat(S{:})-'0';
```

If performance is an issue you can look into other ways to import the strings, but this should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Matlab, but asuming it reads files the same way Octave does, and if using an external tool is OK, you could try replacing the characters to add a delimiter using a text editor. You could change every "0" to "0," and every "1" to "1," and then simply load the file.

(This would add a delimiter at the end of every line. In case that creates a problem, you could try replacing your text by pairs instead "00"->"0,0" "10" -> "1,0" and so on)

In case the file is too big for a normal editor, you might even try replacing the characters with sed:

```
sed -i 's/charactertoreplace/newcharacter/g' yourfile.txt
```